# Capturing output from Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am new to python and testing. I have to do automation testing. I am using the following code to test my webApplication. I am able to use excel to read input data and write test output as Pass or Fail using programming logics without using Assert.

When I am using assert, I am getting output in console, but I am not able to capture it and so I can not push it in excel.

Code I am using is

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest
import os

error = "Houstan you got some error"
assert 2 + 2 == 5, 'error'
```

Output in console

```
xample$ python assert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "assert.py", line 10, in <module>
   assert 2 + 2 == 5, error
AssertionError: Houstan you got some error
```

Can someone help me out to capture this output in some variable so that I can push them in excel in organized way. May be if data can be stored in different variables or in a list.

testdoc.xls

File     -----------     Line     ------    Error

assert.py   ---   10        ------   Houstan you got some error

Comment: Have you considered using the logging library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module is useful for formating and processing error information. for instance

```
import unittest
import os
import traceback

try:
    error = "Houstan you got some error"
    assert 2 + 2 == 5, 'error'
except Exception:
    var = traceback.format_exc()
    # now your traceback is in the variable var
    print ('not failed', var)
    # process the var as you want, then re raise the error
    raise
```

doc is full with examples

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the logging library.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='foo.log',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
try:
    2 + 2 == 5
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('error msg', exc_info=True)
```